# Azure Functions Not Working VS2017

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I've downloaded VS2017 Community Edition to try out Azure functions and I can't get it to work. I've searched many post on Stackoverflow and Azure functions Github pages but nowhere there seems to be a complete documentation about anything.

Here's what I have:

**Azure function:**

```
namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("ngctestqueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "Endpoint=sb://ngcservicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=SERVICE_BUS_KEY")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
}
```

**host.json**

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myQueueItem",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "ngctestqueue",
      "connection": "connection",
      "accessRights": "manage"
    }
  ]
}
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=ngctest2;AccountKey=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=ngctest2;AccountKey=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "AzureWebJobsServiceBus": "Endpoint=sb://ngcservicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=SERVICE_BUS_KEY",
    "connection": "Endpoint=sb://ngcservicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=SERVICE_BUS_KEY"
  }
}
```

**When I run the function via F5 locally, I get the following error:**

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Func
tion1.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK Serv
iceBus connection string 'AzureWebJobsEndpoint=sb://ngcservicebus.servicebus.win
dows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=SERVICE_BUS_KEY' is missing or empty.
```

**My dev environment is as follows:**

1) Windows 8.1 Pro

2) VS2017 Community 15.3.5

3) Azure Functions CLI 1.0.4

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`Connection` property should be set to connection string name, not the value itself. The value will then be read from the config.

```
[ServiceBusTrigger("ngctestqueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")]
```

You don't need to create `host.json` in local environment (it will be auto-generated by SDK).

Comment: Ok, that made the error go away:) But the function is not triggering. There are a few messages in the queue, and also I just added a message, but no output in the console. Any ideas?